# Weird string sorting when 2nd string is longer

Tags: c#, string, sorting

Comparing "î"

```
string.Compare("î", "I ", StringComparison.CurrentCulture) -- returns -1
string.Compare("î", "I ", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) -- returns -1
string.Compare("î", "I", StringComparison.CurrentCulture) -- returns 1 (unexpected)
string.Compare("î", "I", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) -- returns 1  (unexpected)
```

With "i"

```
string.Compare("i", "I ", StringComparison.CurrentCulture) -- returns -1
string.Compare("i", "I ", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) -- returns -1
string.Compare("i", "I", StringComparison.CurrentCulture) -- returns -1
string.Compare("i", "I", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) -- returns 0
```

Current culture was en-GB. I would expect all of these to return 1. Why does having a longer string change the sort order?

Comment: Actually - when I use 'i' not 'î', I get the following result:   string.Compare("i", "I", StringComparison.CurrentCulture) returns -1 string.Compare("i", "I ", StringComparison.CurrentCulture) -1 int

Comment: Update your question with this information.

Comment: Have you tried with other cultures?

Comment: I just tried all cultures in .NET, every one of them return `"î"` vs. `"i"` as +1 and `"î"` vs. `"i "` as -1.

Comment: I would suggest you clarify the question by focusing on the two strings that change sort order by adding the space, it seems there is confusion in the answers to what you're asking about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [UTS#10: Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/) for the full details.

In particular, see section *1.1 Multi-Level Comparison* which explains this behaviour.

There's a table there showing some examples, such as this one:

`role < rôle < roles`

That is analogous to your example with "I" , "î" and "I ", i.e.:

`"I" < "î" < "I "`

except where `roles` has an `s` at the end, your example has a space at the end. But the same logic applies; it's irrelevant what the extra character is - the simple fact that there *is* an extra character makes it sort AFTER the "î".

A crucial point from the spec is:

> Accent differences are typically ignored, if the base letters differ.

The base letters differ if the lengths differ, so the accent differences are ignored in your examples with the space at the end.

However, where the strings are the same length, the accent differences are *not* being ignored - which is exactly the results you are seeing.

Comment: This answer, and that page, is why nobody should write their own text sorting/comparison implementations when dealing with cultural sensitive lists. Granted, there could be bugs in the .NET implementation, but I would guarantee I would have bugs if I wrote my own. Good answer, and good question!

Answer (score 2):

From the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx)

> The comparison terminates when an inequality is discovered or both strings have been compared. **However, if the two strings compare equal to the end of one string, and the other string has characters remaining, then the string with remaining characters is considered greater.** The return value is the result of the last comparison performed.

Comment: string.Compare("î", "I", StringComparison.CurrentCulture) -- returns 1
string.Compare("î", "I ", StringComparison.CurrentCulture) -- returns -1

So - why are î and I deemed equal?

Comment: There is something special about "î" - I don't understand why it doesn't return 0 if its deemed equal to 'I', or if its not equal, change its answer when the length is longer...

Answer (score 0):

Basically because when sorting strings length matters

"a" is smaller than "a " right? makes sense.

Comment: There is something special about "î" - I don't understand why it doesn't return 0 if its deemed equal to 'I', or if its not equal, change its answer when the length is longer...

Comment: Why is "î" compared to "I" +1, while "î" compared to "I " -1?

Comment: you repeated the exact same, what do you mean ?

Answer (score -1):

The behavior is weird, I'll give you that, but I don't see why not use `Ordinal` comparisons given the international context implied here.

For more info, please read [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx).

Comment: The strings are used to provide sort order in the view for some Music metadata. I wanted the result to be culturally sensitive. I guess I could change it to an Ordinal comparison...

Comment: For cultural sensitive text displays, ordinal comparisons and ordering is almost always the wrong choice.